Nginx pods restarted with below error saying epoll_wait() reported that client prematurely closed connection while connecting to upstream
I am using Nginx version 1.24, deployed in GKE. Sometimes, pods restart with liveness and readiness probes failing events. Below are the error logs from the previously restarted container:
2024/05/24 14:09:28 [info] 34#34: *3930371 cache lock timeout, client: 10.91.219.65, server: http://{{k8s-service-name}}:8080,
2024/05/24 14:09:29 [info] 37#37: *4008884 epoll_wait() reported that client prematurely closed connection while connecting to upstream,

Moreover, the upstream server doesn't have any issue with resource utilization and is running fine. Can we get any clues on what might be the exact reason for the restart?
We suspected that a high spike in RPS caused this, so we tried increasing the replicas, but it didn't help.

This is Nginx ingress controller ?
If yes can you please confirm that the  LoadBalancer backend server timeout is 30 seconds?

this is not nginx  ingress controller, its just a nginx pod created with custom nginx configuration.
